# PHP string comparisons not producing the results I expect

Tags: string, compare, digits

I'm very VERY confused!!

```
var_dump('12345678901234567891' == '12345678901234567890');
```

shows `bool(true)`!

I know about "===" but in this example two strings (types are same)!!!
Moreover strings are consists only of DIGITS!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a < php 5.4.4 issue. Try running your code in php 5.4.0 and then try 5.4.4 or greater and you will notice you get different results. To test try an online php sandbox such as http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Also that's a rather old version of php, maybe seeing if it can be upgraded might be a good thing?

Edit: Using === seems to work on older versions of php as you would expect so you should probably use that instead.

Comment: Thx, yes, my local server PHP Version is 5.3.13